# How do I incorporate specified path in batch file for ffmpeg for each?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-file, cmd.exe

If I use this using CMD within the directory where all the movies are, it works fine:

```
for %i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "E:\%i" -map 0 -c copy -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng "E:\converted\%~ni.mp4"
```

I'm trying to create a batch file that allows the user to input a source directory, and output directory. This won't work:

```
set /p filepath=Source File Path
set /p filepath2=Destination File Path
for %i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%filepath%\%i" -map 0 -c copy -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng "%filepath2%\%~ni.mp4"
```

Gives an error:

```
Error: The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~ni.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I incorporate specified path in batch file

Inside a batch file you need to double up the `%`. Something like:

```
for %%i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%filepath%\%%i" -map 0 -c copy -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng "%filepath2%\%%~ni.mp4"
```

> When used as part of a FOR command in a batch file, two %'s are required

Source: [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [For - Loop through files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)